# how is the code for displaying dropdown items in button event?

Tags: iphone, ios

hi all i have implemented code for displaying drapdown items when click on the custom button
but it is not working ios5 give the solution for displaying dropdown items it is too urgent for me in iphone.

```
 units = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Metric(metres)",@"Imperial(feets)",nil];
    dropDownView = [[DropDownView alloc] initWithArrayData:units cellHeight:30 heightTableView:60 paddingTop:-8 paddingLeft:-5 paddingRight:-10 refView:dropdownButton animation:BLENDIN openAnimationDuration:0 closeAnimationDuration:0];
    dropDownView.delegate = self;
    [dropdownButton setTitle:@"Metric(metres)" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:dropDownView.view];
}    
-(void)dropDownCellSelected:(NSInteger)returnIndex{

    [dropdownButton setTitle:[units objectAtIndex:returnIndex] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //[self calculatebuttonaction];
}   

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Class methods

-(IBAction)DropdownButtonClick{
    [dropDownView openAnimation];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about simply to create another UITableView (or UITableViewController) and use it with push/pop functions to display the items of dropdown list with expanding of nothing?